# My average didnt work both in where and having SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, average, where-clause, having-clause

So i have to show the name of the product, id product and unit price for all products whose price exceeds the average price of all products. This is my query

```
select ProductID, ProductName, UnitPrice
from Products
where UnitPrice in
(select UnitPrice
from Products
where avg(UnitPrice)> UnitPrice)
```

but what i got is erro because of aggregat avg(unitprice), when i replace it with having its cause error too. what can i do?

Comment: [Edit] your post to quote the errors in full, not paraphrase them, please.

Comment: You can't write whatever SQL code you want, and expect SQL Server to understand and execute it correctly.  Probably learn some SQL syntax first.

Answer (score 0):

> So i have to show the name of the product, id product and unit price for all products whose price exceeds the average price of all products.

Close.  Use the subquery to return the average and just use that for the comparison:

```
select ProductID, ProductName, UnitPrice
from Products p
where UnitPrice > (select avg(UnitPrice) from Products);
```

Comment: i didnt get my answer, the result is null

Comment: @JessicaMaya . . . First, a query that returns three columns does not return `NULL`.  Second, this query could only return all rows if the `UnitPrice` if the `UnitPrice` was the same or `NULL` on every row.

Answer (score 0):

You could use window functions for this instead of a subquery:

```
select *
from (
    select ProductID, ProductName, UnitPrice, avg(unitPrice) over() avgUnitPrice
    from Products
) p
where UnitPrice > avgUnitPrice
```

Comment: @SteveC: what do you think needs to be fixed in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
with avg_cte(avg_price) as (
    select avg(UnitPrice)
    from Products)
select ProductID, ProductName, UnitPrice
from Products p
     cross join avg_cte a
where p.UnitPrice>a.avg_price;
```